# Android Studio - TextView below ImageView

Tags: java, android, textview, imageview

I'm working with Android Studio and I'm trying with Java to put a TextView below a ImageView. For that, I wrote this code:

```
   //RelativeLayout
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#006699"));

    //Texto: Press to start
    TextView start = new TextView(this);
    start.setId(R.id.startText);
    start.setText("Press to start");
    start.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    start.setTextSize(16);

   //ImageView

    ImageView logo = new ImageView(this);
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("logo", "drawable", getPackageName());
    logo.setImageResource(id);
    logo.setId(R.id.logo);

    //Posición de la imagen

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageDetails = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    imageDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    imageDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    relativeLayout.addView(logo, imageDetails);

    //Text Position:

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textDetails = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    textDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, logo.getId());
    textDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    // start.bringToFront(); It still doesn't appear

    relativeLayout.addView(start, textDetails);

    setContentView(relativeLayout);
```

But when I run that code, it only appears the ImageView on the screen:

[image: Picture]

What's the problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: You want to position the `TextView` **below** the `ImageView` and yet you are using the `ABOVE` rule? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to use `LinearLayout` and then first add `ImageView` then add `TextView`. This will work.

Comment: I tried but still doesn't work :( Dont know why Textview only appears when the ImageView's not added

Answer (score 0):

1>In android application, there is a need of unique id(eg.In layout/main.XML etc. place, id=textview1 like ) for your component(eg. textview,imageview etc.) which you can find it out in your XML file.
You have to use that(id) into your java code to connect backend and forntend.
Then only it your textview work.

2>In other case just check with your layout that other components are not hiding your textview.

Comment: 1. Maybe It could be the key of the problem... I finally made it with the .xml file with the help of Android Studio Design mode, thanks.
2> I think it's not the problem beacuse I tried changing textsize and bringing to front, but it didnt seems to work. 
Thanks for your help =)

Answer (score 0):

There a better solution for this, just use:

```
start.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, R.drawable.logo);
```

That's way you don't need another wrapper view like `RelativeLayout`